# How can I obtain the definite integral of the modified Bessel function of the second kind $K_{i \alpha}(z)$?

Tags: calculus, integration, bessel-functions

I am wondering how to compute the following integral:
$$\int_{x_0}^{\infty} K_{i\alpha}(x) dx$$
where $K_{i\alpha}(x)$ is the modified Bessel function of the second kind, also known as the Bessel function of imaginary argument. Has anyone a reference that performs this integral in this way? I looked for it in [NIST Digital Library of Mathematical Functions](https://dlmf.nist.gov/) and other sources, with no success.

In fact, Ref. [1](https://dlmf.nist.gov/) says that I should find some further relations in Ref. *[A. Apelblat (1983) Table of Definite and Infinite Integrals. Physical Sciences Data, Vol. 13, Elsevier Scientific Publishing Co., Amsterdam.]*, but I have no access to this reference.

Comment: Series expansion of $K_v(x)$ and integrate? To get rid of the $\infty$, try $\int_0^\infty=\int_a^\infty+\int_0^a$ or $x=\frac 1t$

Comment: I tried it because there is a simple result for the integral in $(0,\infty)$, but we continue in trouble with the integral in $(0,a).$

Answer (score 1):

Assuming  $t>0$ , Mathematica returns

$$\int_{t}^{\infty} K_{i\alpha}(x)\,dx=2^{-1+i \alpha } \,\Gamma (i \alpha -1)\, t^{1-i \alpha } \,
   _1F_2\left(\frac{1-i \alpha }{2};\frac{3-i
   \alpha }{2},1-i \alpha ;\frac{t^2}{4}\right)+$$ $$2^{-1-i \alpha }\,
   \Gamma (-i \alpha -1)\, t^{1+i \alpha } \, _1F_2\left(\frac{1+i
   \alpha }{2};\frac{3+i \alpha }{2},1+i
   \alpha ;\frac{t^2}{4}\right)+$$ $$\frac{\pi}{2} \, 
   \text{sech}\left(\frac{\pi  \alpha }{2}\right)$$

Comment: This is useful if we find a relation between $K_{i \alpha}(x)$ and the hypergeometric functions.

Comment: Have a look at https://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/144573825.pdf

Comment: Thank you very much

Comment: @jpbbrito. You are very welcome. Glad to help. Cheers :-)